# why groupby function is not working in this case

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to do mean imputation for car price and the mean price should be based on car model so I tried to make a group by function for my data based on cars model column for the mean imputation but i get this error:

TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment

I tried this

```
grouped_df = df1.groupby('modele')
def replace_zero_or_1000_with_nan(x):
  x[x == 0.0] = pd.np.nan
  x[x == 1000000.0] = pd.np.nan
  return x

# Use apply() to apply the function to the car_price column of each group
grouped_df['prix_millions'] = grouped_df['prix_millions'].apply(replace_zero_or_1000_with_nan)


# Use transform() to apply the mean value of each car model to the NaN values
imputed_df = grouped_df.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

I need to make the values of  0 and 10000 Null values then replace them with mean imputation based on cars model gourps too so the values can be logic.

Comment: `df1['prix_millions'] = grouped_df['prix_millions'].apply(replace_zero_or_1000_with_nan)` and not `grouped_df['prix_millions'] = ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing to replace values 0 and 1000 by the mean of the group:

```
# boolean mask, check where values are 0 and 1000
mask = df['prix_millions'].isin([0, 1000])

# compute the mean for each group
mean_per_group = df.loc[~mask].groupby('modele')['prix_millions'].mean()

# replace 0 and 1000 values by the mean of the group
df.loc[mask, 'prix_millions'] = df['modele'].map(mean_per_group)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   modele  prix_millions
0       1     364.833333
1       1     756.000000
2       1     347.000000
3       1     364.833333
4       1     364.833333
5       1     364.833333
6       1     137.000000
7       1     748.000000
8       1     123.000000
9       1      78.000000
```

Details:

```
>>> m
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: prix_millions, dtype: bool

>>> mean_per_group
modele
1    364.833333
Name: prix_millions, dtype: float64
```

Input:

```
>>> df
   modele  prix_millions
0       1              0
1       1            756
2       1            347
3       1           1000
4       1           1000
5       1              0
6       1            137
7       1            748
8       1            123
9       1             78
```

Answer (score 1):

he error message you received, "TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment," is occurring because you are attempting to assign a value to a groupby object, which is not allowed.

To resolve this issue, you can use the transform method instead of apply when applying your replace_zero_or_1000_with_nan function to the 'prix_millions' column. The transform method applies a function to each group and returns a dataframe with the same shape as the original.

Here's the updated code:

```
grouped_df = df1.groupby('modele')

def replace_zero_or_1000_with_nan(x):
  x[x == 0.0] = pd.np.nan
  x[x == 1000000.0] = pd.np.nan
  return x

# Use transform() to apply the function to the car_price column of each group
grouped_df['prix_millions'] = grouped_df['prix_millions'].transform(replace_zero_or_1000_with_nan)

# Use transform() to apply the mean value of each car model to the NaN values
imputed_df = grouped_df.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

This should allow you to replace the 0 and 10000 values with NaNs, and then impute the mean value of each car model to the NaN values.

Comment: It doesn't change anything since you use `grouped_df['prix_millions'] = ...`. You can't assign to `DataFrameGroupBy` object even if you use `transform` instead of `apply`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is because the groupby method returns the DataFrameGroupBy type, not DataFrame. In fact, do you really need to groupby the dataset before replacing values? I think you can fix it by reordering operations.